# scatter plot using "plot" overlayed with another scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, overlay, scatter

I wanted to make a scatter plot using the "plot" function.I have four columns of data. The data looks like this.

```
Year Tmin P10 P90
1991    18  16.716653   22.00001
1991    21.8    16.69999    21.70001
1991    21.3    16.509979   21.626664
1991    21  16.509979   21.363337
1992    22.6    16.69999    21.70001
1992    21.5    16.509979   21.626664
1992    22  16.509979   21.363337
1992    22.2    16.173316   21.463337
1992    21.5    15.909979   21.70001
1992    22  16.09999    21.90001
1992    22  15.836653   22.263337
```

I use the following code:

```
    dat<-read.csv("D135_tmin.csv",header=TRUE)
    plot(dat$Tmin,xaxt='n',col="red",bg="black",pch=21)
    a<-c(seq(1,3653,365))
    axis(side=1,at=a,labels=T)
    for(b in c(365,731,1096)){
    abline(v=b,lty=3,col=3)
    }
```

I wanted to plot another scatter plot on top of this. But this time, only the values of Tmin when Tmin is greater than P90.
Also,is there a way where I can only show 1991 and 1992 on the xaxis (two values)?

Many thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You can use `points()` to add additional data. Or you can use `plot(..., add = TRUE)`. Pass a character vector to `label` inside your `axis` call. Another option would be to use ggplot2 package.

Comment: On Q2: If you can plot 11 values on the x-axis (which is the length of `a` in your example), you should also be able to plot 2.

Comment: Many Thanks for the help. It seems that ggplot is easier to use than this